# need explanation of 'this' which pass to my method

Tags: java, interface

If I have a class which has an **interface** definition like below;

```
public class FirstClass {

  private static onDragListener listener  

  public interface onDragListener{
      void doSomething();
  }

  //a static method to set on my drag listener
  public static void setOnDragListener(onDragListener listener){
           FirstClass.listener = listener
  }

}
```

As you see above, there is a `setOnDragListener(onDragListener listener)` static method to set on the listener.

Then, there is another class which implements the interface defined in the first class like below:

```
public class SecondClass implements onDragListener{
    public void initialize(){
          FirstClass.setOnDragListener(this); //my question is here about 'this'. 
    }
}
```

My question is why I can use `this` as the argument pass to the `FirstClass.setOnDragListener(this);` in the `initialize()` method above?

I mean the `setOnDragListener(onDragListener listener)` is expecting a `onDragListener` type argument to pass in, does `this` in the `initialize` method of second class means the real implementation of the interface or how can I understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance is a `is-a` relationship.

`SecondClass` is-a `onDragListener`.

`this` is a `SecondClass`.

Ergo, `this` is a `onDragListener`.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you're refering to the object itself which will be implementing the onDragListener.

Answer (score 0):

`setOnDragListener()` expects an `onDragListener` interface to be passed as argument. `SecondClass` implements `onDragListener` interface, so you can pass `this` from a `SecondClass` instance to `FirstClass.setOnDragListener()`, because `this` implements `onDragListener`

Answer (score 0):

As your SecondClass implements the onDragListener interface it can be used anywhere an onDragListener is needed because it is an onDragListener.

The 'this' in the call to FirstClass.setOnDragListener(this) is the current instance of SecondClass which is an onDragListener.